# Is it possible to check how loud someone is speaking in Discord with a Discord Bot

Tags: discord, discord.js, volume

I just wanted to ask if someone knows if it is possible to check how loud someone is speaking in discord because someone on my Discord is always raging and we want to mute him if he reaches a specific number of decibels.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way to do that would be to analyze the voice data directly and since the API requires it to be encrypted (see: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/voice-connections#encrypting-and-sending-voice ), you wouldn't be able to do that.

That said, you could just mute him directly with the interface provided.